# How to loop through an array and create substrings from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, substring

I am trying to parse through HTML validation errors by adding the errors to an array, and then looping through the array, strip out the first part of the error (e.g. ValidationError line 23 col 40:) and then I want to only keep the text inside the single quotes and save that to a new list.

Here is what I have working, but I know it's not scalable and only works with the String fullText and not with the ArrayList list so that's what I need help with. Thank you!

```
package htmlvalidator;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ErrorCleanup {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Saving the raw errors to an array list
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Add the text to the first spot
    list.add("ValidationError line 23 col 40:'Bad value ius-cors for attribute name on element meta: Keyword ius-cors is not registered.'");

    //Show what is in the list
    System.out.println("The full error message is: " + list);       

    String fullText = "ValidationError line 23 col 40:'Bad value ius-cors for attribute name on element meta: Keyword ius-cors is not registered.'";

    //Show just the actual message
    System.out.println("The actual error message is: " + fullText.substring(fullText.indexOf("'") + 1));


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> msgs = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : list) {
    msgs.add(s.replaceAll(".*'(.*)'.*", "$1"));
}
list = msgs;
```

Using regex to extract the string is cleaner and still scalable enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following loop:

```
    ArrayList<String> errorFullTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> errorMessageTexts = new ArrayList<>();

    //Add the text to the first spot, you can add as many as you would like
    errorFullTexts.add("ValidationError line 23 col 40:'Bad value ius-cors for attribute name on element meta: Keyword ius-cors is not registered.'");

    for(String errorFullText : errorFullTexts){
        errorMessageTexts.add(errorFullText.substring(errorFullText.indexOf(":'")+2, errorFullText.lastIndexOf(".'")));
    }
```